# Ignore file_get_contents if it fails

Tags: php

I'm using a site to get users' country from their IP address, but the site was down for a while yesterday and caused a ton of problems for me.

How can I **IGNORE** a `file_get_contents()` if it fails?

This is what I'm trying but it doesn't work, still burps if it doesn't work:

```
if($details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"))){
    $country =  $details->country;  
}
```

I've seen other answers which say turn off error reporting which to me is a bad, bad, bad, idea.

**Is there a better way OR a better way to get country code from IP address?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [stream context](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) with the `ignore_errors` option.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('ignore_errors' => true)));
$json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}", false, $context);
```

The bonus here is that you'll also get to see the error message that the site is sending back to you.

Comment: Oh nice, I forgot about that option :D

Comment: Is this better than your cURL solution @Jack? If so, why? I was just going to accept it.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney This answer allows you to keep using `file_get_contents()` almost unchanged, so in that sense it's better :) I've also deleted my answer hehe

Comment: @salathe -- if you could also mention that `$json` needs to be checked if it is empty before trying to use `json_decode` so you don't get errors with that.

Comment: @MihaiStancu the question isn't about ignoring errors from `json_encode()`; even if it were, you've mentioned it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Calling `json_decode(file_get_contents(somefunct(someotherfunc())))` might look nice and short. But it ignores 4 levels of error checking and allows functions down the call stack to receive unexpected arguments. That's why I said it should be mentioned (in the answer). Because this StackOverflow page will (in time) become a resource for other to learn from.

Comment: My answer doesn't contain any nested function calls.  It is up to the end-user to see what `$json` contains and behave appropriately. I'm not going to add unnecessary bumpf to a correct and concise answer to the question asked, which was about quietening the warnings generated by `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should be okay:

```
try{
  if($details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"))){
    $country =  $details->country;  
  }
} catch( Exception $e )
{
  //log or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: No exceptions are thrown with either `file_get_contents()` or `json_decode()`.

Comment: @goto and Jack, you can use an error handler to throw exceptions -- virtually making all (or some) of your errors to behave like exceptions.

Comment: Most frameworks do this because they can catch most errors and show a nice backtrace while your debuging and they can also make sure that catchable errors don't perturb the output buffer or header redirects etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($cont = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}")) && is_object($details = json_decode($cont))) {
    $country =  $details->country;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) returns false on failure.

```
$country = "Unknown";
if(false !== ($details = json_decode(@file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}")))){
    $country = $details->country;
}
if($country !== "Unknown"){
    // here you go
}
```